# Is there a Word processing software built for inline annotations, references and line count?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-writer, word-processor

I think this is a tall order for Libreoffice, my regular processor. The goal is a column of narrative with annotations in one margin when needed and references on the other. The appearance of 5, 10, 15, 20 for line counting would be a welcomed perk.

I'll want the font to change and formatting to change artistically so the features have to be dynamic, not baked in. Columns in Libreoffice just accept overflow from the previous column instead of the same type of column from the previous page - so THIS is the basis of my search. I can do this on only ONE page in Libreoffice.

Comment: Sounds like a job for LaTeX.

Comment: Most powerful little tool I'd never heard of. I need time to examine this but suspect it's the thing.

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is the right site for this question, since it's not about programming per se.  If you want to know how to do specific things with LibreOffice, try http://superuser.com.  If you want suggestions for alternative software, try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this in LibreOffice. The first is to create a single table with one row and three columns. I found this to be the easiest to work with.

However, [line numbering does not work for tables](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/231700/line-numbering-skips-table/). So you may want the second way instead, which is to create 3 frames with *Insert -> Frame*. Specify to anchor `As Character`. Then go to *Tools -> Line Numbering* and mark *Lines in text frames*.

A related question is at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/55855/how-can-i-get-two-separate-columns-of-text-in-librewriter/.